# Cannot change text size in rgl plot

Tags: r, ubuntu, rgl

I have a problem changing the text size of a 3d plot I generated with the package rgl. Everything works fine, but I can't effectively change the cex properties of an 3d object. I run R 2.14.1 (2011-12-22) under 64bit Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (2.6.32-37-generic). As an example see the following code (I found on Stack Overflow):

```
library(rgl) 
set.seed(1001) 
n <- 20 
text3d(runif(n),runif(n),runif(n),LETTERS[1:n],cex=seq(0.5,5,length=n))
```

The letters have all the same size when I plot them.

Any help is highly appreciated! Best Regards.

Frieder Schillinger

Comment: Seem so be an Ubuntu problem. Your code works for me (Windows, same R, rgl 092.789)

Answer (score 2):

Weird. It works for me on Ubuntu 10.04 (rgl 0.92.829) [this is my code, I think].  Can you tell us your `rgl` version?  By "plot" do you mean rendering the picture on the screen, or producing PostScript output?  This was fixed in the most recent (0.92.829) version:

```
> news(grepl("text",Text),package="rgl")
Changes in version 0.92.829:

    o   rgl.postscript() now adjusts the size of text following the cex setting.
       The font and family settings are still ignored.

    o   Transparency in material textures was not always rendered properly.
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt replies! And sorry for being imprecise: with “plot” I meant “rendering”. I installed the rgl package (version 0.89) via 
    `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rgl`
since I could not manage to install it directly in R (same error message as reported by other users, e.g. [link](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/package-ca-rgl-for-ubuntu-td3075070.html)). I also double-checked installing  rgl  (0.92.798) successfully in R on my laptop (also Ubuntu 10.04 LTS) and the code works! So I might try to tackle the problems I had in the first place installing rgl within R on my desktop PC.

Answer (score 0):

```
?text3d
```

There is no cex argument. You should be using "scale".