# rgl plot: point size does not change when saving as postscript

Tags: r, rgl

I'm trying to generate a 3d scatterplot using rgl. It looks great on my screen, but whenever I export it as a PDF (or any other postscript format) it completely ignores any size specifications I use.

(I'm running RGui v.2.15.1 and rgl v.0.92.892 on a Macbook under Mountain Lion.)

For example:

```
library(rgl) 
set.seed(1982) 
points3d(runif(5),runif(5),runif(5), size=20)
# points look huge
rgl.postscript('testplot.pdf', fmt='pdf')
# points look tiny
```

Does anyone have an idea for a way to get this to work? The resolution of the images I get using `rgl.snapshot` don't look so good, and I would really like to get a vector image for this plot.

Also, I followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214298/cannot-change-text-size-in-rgl-plot) and I got text to resize just fine, but not points. So I thought one way to work around this would be to plot my points as text using a circle as my character, but I couldn't get rgl to accept symbols or expressions either...

Comment: Help file states that only `png` device is currently supported.

Answer (score 4):

Confirmed on Windows, look like some paper size scaling problem. You might try

```
spheres3d(runif(5),runif(5),runif(5),radius=0.1)
```

as a workaround if you can live with real 3d.

Comment: Thanks! I tested and it worked (I'll just add to your answer in that I got rid of the 3d "feel" of spheres by using `lit=F` in the `spheres()` command. This way they look very similar to dot points)

Comment: That works, but be cautious: spheres need much more resources, and with a few thousands of them, interactivity may become sluggish.